# Remember me feature on ThinkTecture Identity server client website

Tags: asp.net, .net, cookies, identityserver3

In my solution I am using Thinktecture IdentityServer. 
I wanted to introduce the remember me feature (persistant cookie) so I used `AllowRememberMe` option described here: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/authenticationOptions.html

and that is working good but the persistant cookie is created only for IdentityServer instance - not for the client website which called for authentication.

My question is: Is there out of the box solution to achieve that? or do I have somehow pass deatils about cookie expiration through claims or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course identity server can only issue cookies for itself - not your applications. You would need to do that in your application code.

Comment: Thanks! But now the problem is that 'rememberMe' model property is only visible in internal IdentityServer classes. I mean that for now I am unable to get the login post request values. So actually after login action there is no way (on client website) to distinguish if user ticked that remember me checkbox or not.

Comment: Yes. The lifetime of the authentication session in idsrv and your app are independent.